# SSIS best way to load configuration to custom script

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS 2012 and i need to figure out the best way to load multiple configuration files to be used in a custom script.

This is the way it goes:

- I need to use a custom script to access a NoSQL database
- In this case, the NoSQL database has no rigid schema, therefore the attribute change from document to document
- I want to use configuration  files to tell how the columns are supposed to be renamed and configure there other basic rules.

the above task is easily done in c#, however if possible i would like read the configuration files using a SSIS component (to read a flat file, excel file or database rules). Therefore i want to know how can i feed the custom script with the data from the stream, the scipt consumes stream (the stream contains the configuration), and after consuming the entire stream, the script component generates rows.

An example case would be be:

1. script reads an entire stream of numbers.
2. the script orders the numbers on the stream
3. the script discards duplicates the script
4. outputs the ordered sequence of numbers without duplicates.

Comment: I'm rather confused by your question, perhaps it's lack of blood in my teastream. You have a data in a NoSQL database. Based on the current configuration, you extract data that has shape X. The next configuration change can result in data that has shape Y? The desire is to make this work in an SSIS package?

Comment: @billinkc yes and no. I only need to know how to use the incoming stream as a configuration stream. Hence the example case of the number ordering. Once the configuration is loaded I can dynamically construct the adapters (I don't need help for this, I only want to use the input stream as configuration).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the NoSql database and configuration files just background of the problem and what you really need is an asynchronous
script component to read everything from the pipeline, then do something and finally send the results back to the pipeline?
If so then what you need is create an script component with it's output buffer set to SynchronousInputId=None.
The example of the numbers to be deduped and sorted that you posted could then be solved with the following pseudo-code 
(assume you create an output column in the output buffer of the script component called "numberout" 
and output buffer property SynchronousInputId is set to None) :

```
...
public override void PreExecute()
 {
     base.PreExecute();

    CREATE ARRAY TO HOLD NUMBERS
 }

 public override void PostExecute()
 {
     base.PostExecute();

    SORT AND DEDUPE ARRAY

    FOR EACH N IN ARRAY:
        output0buffer.addrow()
        output0byffer.numberout=N

 }

 public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
 {
    INSERT NUMBER TO ARRAY
 }
```